# Use of static keyword to global variable in c

Tags: c, static, global-variables

If I apply static keyword to local variable, its value is maintained within function invocations. However, if I apply static keyword to global variable, will it be as good as declaring the variable as global? What I mean to say is does static keyword has any effect on global variables?

Comment: Global `static` variables (and functions) are local to the source file - they have internal linkage.

Answer (score 1):

It means that variable has file scope. You cannot access that global variable (by name) from another file.